# Python expected a character buffer object

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a script that reads a file, finds today's and yesterday's date and then prints all of the content between those two dates. However whenever I try to run this, I get expected a character buffer object on the last line.

```
import datetime
import re
today = datetime.date.today().day
yesterday = (today - 1)
file=open("test.txt","r")
s = file.read()
start = today
end = yesterday

print((s.split(start))[1].split(end)[0])
```

Comment: `.split()` expects a string, not an integer.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There's no need for the extra parentheses in `(s.split(start))[1]`, and there's already a lot of parentheses, especially if you add `str`, so they're worth removing. Just write `s.split(start)[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start` and `end` are integers not strings ... you cannot split a string on an integer

```
"some5string".split(5) # wont work it needs a string
"some5string".split("5") # will work
```

change it to

```
print((s.split(str(start)))[1].split(str(end))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`start` and `end` are `int`s which cannot be passed as arguments to `split`.

```
>>> "234".split(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

You could convert them to strings but I don't really think that's enough. Simply using the `day` field of a date just gives you a number, not a full date:

```
>>> datetime.date.today().day
25
```

This probably isn't enough data for parsing. Look into date formatting in Python.

Comment: Thanks, but for the files I'm using the dates are just numbers, not complete dates :)

Comment: Well then I hope you're being really careful and preferably only running this once because there's all sorts of ways that could go wrong. For example all the other data in the files shouldn't contain numbers, and the files can only contain certain combinations of dates (e.g. if the file contains data from the 29th of Feb to the 2nd of March, a space of just 3 days, you can expect bugs).